# Prove that $\vec a_i^T T \vec a_j=\delta_{ij}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, classical-mechanics

> Given a solution of the small oscillation equations (called normal mode)
>
> $$\vec q = \sum_i c_i \vec a_i \cos (\omega_i t - \gamma_i), \ \ \ 1 \leq i \leq n \tag1$$
>
> Where
>
> $$\vec q=
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     q_1  \\
>     .  \\
>     .  \\
>     q_n  \\
>     \end{pmatrix}
> , \ \ \ \ \vec a=
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>    a_1  \\
>     .  \\
>     .  \\
>     a_n  \\
>     \end{pmatrix}\tag2$$
>
> And given the following equation for $\vec a$
>
> $$(\omega_i^2T-V) \vec a_i=0\tag3$$
>
> Show that
>
> $$\vec a_i^T T \vec a_j=\delta_{ij}\tag4$$
>
> Where $T$ and $V$ are real, positive definite and symmetric matrices.

I am convinced $(4)$ can be shown by means of $(3)$

$$\omega_j^2T\vec a_j=V \vec a_j$$

$$\omega_j^2\vec a_i^T T\vec a_j=\vec a_i^T V \vec a_j$$

But how to advance?

Comment: We are missing some important information about the nature of $T$ and $V$. In particular, in order for (4) to hold it must be the case $a_i^T V a_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$, which we cannot deduce from the given information

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for your comment. $T$ and $V$ besides being real, positive definite and symmetric, are diagonal. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You need to know the $\omega_i^2$ are distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally got it!

Let's have a look at equation $(3)$, where $1 \leq i,j \leq n$

$$(\omega_j^2T-V) \cdot \vec a_j=0\tag3 \Rightarrow V\cdot \vec a_j=\omega_j^2T\cdot \vec a_j$$

We notice that $(3)$ is basically the eigenvalue equation, where $\vec a_j$ is an eigenvector of $V$ *with respect to $T$*.

There're $\vec a_j$ eigenvectors with $n$ corresponding distinct eigenvalues (let us set $\lambda_j:= \omega^2_j$)

$$V\cdot \vec a_1=\lambda_1 T\cdot \vec a_1 \tag{5.1}$$

$$V\cdot \vec a_2=\lambda_2 T\cdot \vec a_2 \tag{5.2}$$

$$\text{....................}$$

$$V\cdot \vec a_n=\lambda_n T\cdot \vec a_n \tag{5.n}$$

All we have to do is show orthogonality of eigenvectors. For the proof we only need two eigenvectors so let us left-multiply $(5.2)$ by $\vec a_1^T$ both sides to get

$$\vec a_1^T \cdot V \cdot \vec a_2=\lambda_2 \vec a_1^T \cdot T \cdot \vec a_2 \tag6$$

OK now we get another equation for $\vec a_1^T \cdot V \cdot \vec a_2$ exploiting the fact that $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of $V$

$$\vec a_1^T \cdot V \cdot \vec a_2 = (V \cdot \vec a_1)^T \cdot \vec a_2 = (\lambda_1 T\cdot \vec a_1)^T \cdot \vec a_2 = \lambda_1 \vec a_1^T \cdot T \cdot \vec a_2 \tag7$$

Equating $(6)$ and $(7)$

$$(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)(\vec a_1^T \cdot T \cdot \vec a_2)=0 \tag8$$

As $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$, we indeed need

$$\vec a_1^T \cdot T \cdot \vec a_2=0 \tag9$$

OK but what if $\vec a_i^T \cdot T \cdot \vec a_i$? Well as $T$ is positive definite $ \Rightarrow \vec a_i^T \cdot T \cdot \vec a_i \geq 0$. It follows that we can always scale the amplitude vectors such that

$$\vec a_i^T \cdot T \cdot \vec a_i=1 \tag{10}$$

Combining $(9)$ and $(10)$ we indeed get orthonormality

$$\vec a_i^T T \vec a_j=\delta_{ij}\tag4$$

Comment: Yes, you need the $\lambda_i$ to be distinct, but nowhere in the original problem did you state that?

Comment: Hi Ted I indeed forgot to state it in the original question. Next time I post I'll try to include more details.